# Finder Sync extension Xcode template issue

Tags: findersync

I've tried the Finder Sync Xcode provided template, just changed the working directory, but it fails:

- extension installation log shows in /var/log/system.log and the extension shows in the Pref Panes, but:
- no icon overlay shows,
- no program log in /var/log/system.log
- /var/log/system.log reads many lines like:

  > Oct 23 17:46:50 Mac iconservicesagent[589]: -[ISGenerateImageOp generateImageWithCompletion:] Failed to composit image for descriptor <ISBindingImageDescriptor: 0x7f8bac3057e0>.
  >
  > Oct 23 17:46:50 Mac quicklookd[15178]: Error returned from iconservicesagent: (null)

According to the code, the template should already display icon overlays, but the log is not verbose and debugging is not possible (is it?). Moreover, the NSLog calls are expected to display somewhere (otherwise why are they in the Xcode template?).

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `os_log()` to print to the console from the running Extension. Helps a lot with debugging.